# I don't understand how to get the realm server running on the AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, realm

I got AWS running an instance of the AMI service using this ami-80347097 from the Realm website. So I have the EC2 instance up now, but I don't know what to do next. Sorry I'm completely new to this sort of thing.

What would be the server URL for the AWS Instance? And would the admin access token for the Object Server still be the same? Or would I have to do something specific in the EC2 Instance?
TT.TT

**EDIT:** 
Ok so I got the Object dashboard to actually work and I am able to log in.
Thank you very much for helping me with that. My last step is actually getting connected to the Object Server. What would the Server URL for the Object Server be?

I tried using the realm://public URL:9080 for the server URL and got this error [Realm Sync Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVup7.png)

[Server Connection Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fjt5.png)

Comment: Can you connect to your EC2 instance via ssh ? Have you enabled the realm-object-server service & 9080 port for object dashboard? @Panda Life

Comment: Yes I was able to connect to my EC2 Instance via SSH. I believe I enabled the realm-object-server by running these commands: 
sudo systemctl enable realm-object-server
sudo systemctl start realm-object-server
However I did not know how to enable the 9080 port for the object dashboard. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have successfully initiated the **ami-80347097** instance with **realm-object-server** service running. At this point make sure you have enabled the **9080** port in your inbound rules section. This is necessary because you are going to access the realm object dashboard with the port enabled.

**Steps:**

1. Goto EC2 Dashboard
2. Select "Securit Group" under "Network & Security"
3. Click on the security group you have been using for the **ami-80347097** instance
4. Once you have clicked the security group a configuration tab "Description", "Inbound", "Outbound", "Tags" will appear at the bottom of the screen
5. Add the port **9080** in your Inbound section as a Custom TCP Rule

[image]

Once you are done doing this,

Open a new browser window and go to http://localhost:9080. The login page for the Realm Dashboard will be displayed. Remember to replace localhost with the IP address of your server.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear instructions to get my Realm Dashboard up and running. The last thing I need to do is get the Object Server up and running. I added more information in my Edit

Comment: Are you trying to connect with the server via Realm Browser app?

Comment: Yes. Is that unnecessary? Could I just do it through code?

Comment: I found that there are some issues with the older version of Realm Browser. Could you please re-check if you are running the latest version of Realm Browser?

Comment: My Realm Browser version is 2.0.1 which is the most recent one in the app store. The steps I took to connect were to open the app, press Connect to Object Server, type in the server URL which I assume is realm://Local_IP_Address for the Amazon EC2 instance:9080/, and set my admin access token to the one I had before,

Comment: Hi.  I have setup the ami-80347097 instance.  I cannot see the realm file, are they supposed to be installed?